# Windows Task Manager not showing all cores?

Tags: cpu, task-manager, xeon, multi-processor

I have Fujitsu RX200 S6 servers, which are Xeon 5500/5600 compatible.  Up to today, I had dual X55nn (not sure of exact model) installed.  Windows Task Manager was showing 24 separate graphs.  I was able to reference 24 threads in VM.  All made sense.  Today I purchased and installed X5675.  CPU-Z reports both processors.  Question: I expected to see 48 graphs in Task Manager with these newer processors, but I am seeing only 16.  Why 16?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about tell us what version of Windows your running.  Windows has limits on the number of cores it supports depending on the version.  It would help to know exact specifications.

Answer (score 0):

After more reading, I determined that dual 5600 Xeon CPUs will show as 24 graphs in Task Manager, which is what I am seeing.  I made the wrong assumption that HT will double the count to 48.